# Backbone model: nested data structure

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I'm developing backbone app, which makes crossdomain restful request. The nested data structure in request are required, in the curl request I have that structure:

```
{
    "site_id": 1,
    "post": {
        "site_id": 1,
        "provider_id": 1,
        "provider_post_id":1,
        "created_ts": "12.12.12",
        "post": {
            "header": "text",
            "caption": "text",
            "image": "http://...jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

In the model I have not nested structure and this is pretty comfortable, because I use `image` model field in the `view` (DOM element creation).

**What the correct way to send nested data to server from Backbone app?**

Model:

```
var WraperModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'http://mydomain/core/api/v1/bookmarklet_post/?  callback=?',
    defaults: {
        site_id: 1, // shouldn't be hardcoded
        type:"type", site_id:2, provider_id: 2, provider_post_id: 2,  created_ts:2,
        header : '',
        caption: '',
        image: ''
    },
});
```

The part of view, which use `image` model property:

```
drawItem: function (model) {
    var inst = new ImageView({model: model, tagName: 'li',     className:'images-item'}).render();
    this.imagesWrapper.append(inst.el);
},
getImages: function () {
   var images = doc.getElementsByTagName('img'),
       view = this;
   _.each(images, function (image) {
       image.offsetHeight > 75 
       && image.offsetWidth > 75 &&
       view.collection.add({image: image.src});
   });
},
```

The part of another view, which send data to server.

```
sendTo: function(){
    var that = this,
    data = {saving: true};

    $('#add-header').val() && (data.header = $('#add-header').val());
    $('#add-description').val() && (data.caption = $('#add-description').val());
    this.model.set(data);
    this.model.save();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first parameter you pass in `save` is a hash of the attributes that are going to be passed along in your save.

In your `sendTo` function just build up an object with the data from your model and any additional form values in a way that the server expects.  By default, when a save is successful the data from the response will be passed through the parse method and set back on the model.

```
var myData = {
     //create nested object for the server
};

this.model.save(myData);
```

Comment: Good solution! I was processed the data on server side, in this time.