# Backbone Nested Models... how do they work?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I'm using Backbone for my web application and I'm having trouble figuring out how to work with nested models.  I have a model based on a java class whos JSON would look something like this:

```
"AdminSettings":
{
    "defaults": {
        "deletable":true,
        "transferable":false;
        "issueLimit":1
    }
    "displaySettings": {
        "tabs":2,
        "amounts:[10,20]
    }
}
```

Currently, I have an endpoint set up and a backbone model for the AdminSettings object.  I was wondering if there was a specific way to get all the backbone benefits for the objects inside AdminSettings.  For example, currently I have to use:

```
adminSettings.get("defaultValues").shareable
```

But I want to use:

```
adminSettings.get("defaultValues").get("shareable")
```

This isn't the only benefit I'm trying to obtain, just an example.

So yeah, what would be a good way to go about this.  I was thinking making a backbone model for each one of the nested objects and setting up endpoints for each one of those, but I'm not completely sure.  Anyways, thanks for looking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backbone model: nested data structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769649/backbone-model-nested-data-structure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own custom backbone parser:

```
var DisplaySettingsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var DefaultValuesModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var AdminSettingsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    model: {
        defaultValues: DefaultValuesModel
        displaySettings:  DisplaySettingsModel
    },

    parse: function(response){
        response["defaultValues"] = new DefaultValuesModel(response["defaultValues"], {parse:true});
        response["displaySettings"] = new DisplaySettingsModel(response["displaySettings"], {parse:true});
        return response;
    }
});
```